# Stop Menu showing on log-in page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am currently developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 application and have referenced the [Authorise] method to show the log-in on entry. Although this stops the use of the top menu (at the moment it simply is standard "home "index") They are still visible and I wish to hide them from the log-on screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Chri3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
 <div>Code for your menu</div>
}
```